# What is causing game to minimize?

Tags: windows-7

My full screen applications have started randomly minimizing. I would have guessed this is some kind of anti-virus or update thing, but I can't pin it down. I've tried closing every running program but it still happens. Is there some way to determine exactly what process is causing this? Or else is there a way to force an application to stay in the foreground?

This only happens when I don't press any keys or mouse buttons for a few seconds. As long as I am actively doing something in the game, it will stay in the foreground.

Comment: Try a different keyboard. I suspect one or more of your buttons is sticking.

Comment: I will try that. I also forgot to mention, the minimizing only happens when I stop pressing keys or the mouse.

Comment: That could definitely be a sticky key, or a faulty USB port / bus.